# Publish VM in azure market place.

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Created a VM image in azure classic portal, then used that image file to create vm and generated a test report using azure certified test tool.
Publish the VM image in Azure publish portal https://publish.windowsazure.com
It is in 0% of progress in staging state and also shows the below error message with it.Failure: SAS url is not well formed. (Requires Publisher Action)
I could not stop the staging process and there is no option to delete the virtual machine details in azure publish portal.
Also it is not showing option to upload test report of vm image.Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when creating the SAS url using the latest version of storage explorer. Try using version [6](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to create the url and push to staging again (a new request).